# how casbin can be used for abac with large user base

Tags: spring-boot, rbac, casbin

I am trying to use [casbin](https://casbin.org/) for my project ABAC and RBAC

I am stuck in understanding this marchers

```
[request_definition]
r = sub, obj, act

[policy_definition]
p = sub, obj, act

[role_definition]
g = _, _

[policy_effect]
e = some(where (p.eft == allow))

[matchers]
m = g(r.sub, p.sub) && keyMatch(r.obj, p.obj) && (r.act == p.act || p.act == "*")
```

I need help in understanding this config file matching with policy file how exactly matchers works?

Comment: See scaling ABAC: https://casbin.org/docs/en/abac#scaling-the-model-for-complex-and-large-number-of-abac-rules